# Select on same date as timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to fetch one or several rows from the databases (depedning on results) for a flight ID and a given date. 
However, I do not know how I can do that. I got the flightId (called flight in table) and I got a unixtimestamp for the date of the flight.

What should my query look like?

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `flight` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flight` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` mediumtext,
  `date_original` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_current` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

***Edit*** 
I have tried several queries, but since I only have the timestamp I can't seem to figure out how to get it from a timestamp to a datetime concerning only the date in question. The timestamp gives an exact second of the day, however, I need to search the whole day (e.g. 2013-04-26 00:00:00 to 2013-04-26 23:59:59)...
So basically, I can't get futher than...

```
SELECT date_original, notes FROM flight WHERE flight = '{$a_sFlightId}' AND date_original ...?
```

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Comment: Why are you trying to match based on a date when you have the flight ID? Use the flight ID.

Comment: @Sammitch Flight IDs are reused on multiple dates.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Tried different once, but can't seem to figure out how to get it from a timestamp to the datetime.

Comment: @PaulPeelen Will you update your question to show what you tried? Without your code, your question is simply a "I can haz teh codez?" request.

Comment: Sorry about that, has been a long day ;). I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE date(from_unixtime($your_unix_timestamp)) = date(date_original)
```